# how to make this effect in Compose? so that the map is blurred, but the image is not blurred on it

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to make this effect in Compose? so that the map is blurred, but the image is not blurred on it,

when I set blur, it blurs everything,

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MovieListItem(
    movie: Movies,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .width(150.dp)
        .blur(20.dp)) {
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                containerColor = Color.Red
            )
        ) {}
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
        ) {
            AsyncImage(
                model = Constants.BASE_IMAGE + movie.posterPath, contentDescription = "Image",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .aspectRatio(9 / 14f)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(20.dp)),
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
            )
            Text(text = movie.title, modifier = Modifier.width(150.dp))
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can refer this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77557168/5457853